# how ReBind a GridView with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i want to ReBind a `GridView`  with Jquery. I am Using `SignalR` and want when a client receive  Notification message , the GridView be Rebind, like `GridView.DataBind()` in code behind.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function () {

         // i want ReBind here
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        });
    });
</script>
```

any idea ?

Comment: already googled 'bind gridview client side'?

Comment: yes , but that solutions Bind new Data to gridView but i dont need adding new Data, only need `Gridview.DataBind();`

Comment: Gridview.DataBind() mean bind a datasource, so maybe you can evaluate the possibility to bind the grid client side from start, for example by JSON injected, so you could call webmethod to refresh your JSON datasource and then refresh your grid after message received